# Objective-C subclasses question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, subclass

I have a class called Level, which is a subclass of NSObject.

Then I have a class called Level_1_1 which is a subclass of Level.

Is it allowed to type like

```
Level* aLevel = [Level_1_1 alloc];
```

instead of

```
Level_1_1* theLevel = [Level_1_1 alloc];
```

? :)

I try it and I don't get any warnings, just wondering if it's okay to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is allowed; but there are two things you should keep in mind:

1. Never, ever call `+alloc` without chaining it with `-init` or an `-initWith*`, unless you are mucking about with the runtime.
2. You might want to reconsider your design if you are calling classes things like `Level_1_1`. You might, for example, want to have a generic `Level` class and some manner of level description data tied to it, so you don't have to hard-code every level; making stuff pretty much impossible to extend without massive effort on your part.

Back to the point:

```
SomeClass *aSomeclass = [[MySomeClass alloc] init];
```

is perfectly acceptable (assuming `MySomeClass` inherits from `SomeClass`). In fact, this happens a lot without you even noticing: You never, for example, actually get an `NSString`, even when calling `[[NSString alloc] init]`, as in:

```
// This is an NSConstString masquerading as an NSString
NSString *aString = @"This is an NSConstString";
// This probably gives you an NSConcreteString, or something of the kind
NSString *anotherString = [NSString stringWithString:aString];
```

You could even add a completely wrong type to your class. E.g.

```
NSArray *someString = @"Not An Array!";
NSLog(@"%s", [someString UTF8String]);  // this works, but creates
                                        // a compile-time warning
NSLog(@"%u", [someString count]);       // this creates a runtime error,
                                        // but none while compiling
```

This string instances is still perfectly usable, *but the compiler can't warn you about obvious errors anymore, because it thinks it's an NSArray.* Also, Objective-C 2.0 properties won't work properly (but the compiler is gonna warn you about it.).

Comment: Thanks a lot. ;) I don't use alloc, I use new, which I assume is alloc and init in one. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Then please use `#new` it in your examples and please don't assume what `#new` does but look it up in the documentation.